# can we add the file dynamic by using jquery in ror

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application i have 2 html form (edit,_experiecnce) ,in edit form i have one link whenever i link this link i want to add the _experience form on edit form. this can be done dynamic by using jquery
can some write the jquery method.Please

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you may simply consider rendering the experience partial in a div within the form & set the display to none via CSS.  Then with jQuery, you can leverage `$('#divid').show()` when the link is clicked (see: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Basic_Show_and_Hide)

If that is not what you want, you may need to look into using AJAX to retrieve the form.

Hope this helps a bit.